# WebViewer html file will not Load

Tags: webview, android-webview

I have problems loading my local html in to webView in my Application heres the code -

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weekly);
    WebView ww = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewer5);
    ww.addJavascriptInterface(new myJsInterface(this), "Android");
    ww.loadUrl("file:///assets/pro/index.html");
```

The Result from the App says:

Webpage Not available
the Web page at file:///assets/pro/index.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

The HTML file works fine alone or in a browser just not in the webViewer.

Answer (score 1):

assets folder should be accessed using file:///android_asset.  change to below:

`ww.loadUrl(" "file:///android_asset/pro/index.html");   or ww.loadUrl(" "file:///android_asset/index.html");`  (since i cant see your directory structure)

Comment: CAN SOMEONE GIVE ME A VOTE FOR THIS